# Why do these calls happen in the order they do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a function to query data from a MongoDB database and return all objects in the form of an array. Here is my code:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert')
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/stuff'; //database from which to select is at the end of the path

var myArray = [];
function findStuff(db) {
   var cursor =db.collection('images').find( );
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         console.dir(doc);
         myArray.push(doc);
         console.log(myArray.length)
      } else {
          db.close();
          console.log("Done with function...");
      }
   });
};
```

Here is a test I wrote to see if findStuff correctly sets myArray to an array of the objects in the collection:

```js
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  findStuff(db);
  console.log("Length of myArray:");
  console.log(myArray.length);
  for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    console.log("Hello"); //This is here to show that the for-loop runs
  };
});
```

When I run the code using Node, I get the following:

```
Length of myArray:
0
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'U2eCs/®\tÿ$' },
  id: 1,
  name: 'Tree with sunset 0',
  url: 'http://goo.gl/TgH49m' }
1
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'U2ÇCs/®\tÿ%' },
  id: 2,
  name: 'Hills n Clouds',
  url: 'http://goo.gl/VXjdSa' }
2
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'U;\'ó\u0010oiÒ\u001cé' },
  id: 3,
  name: 'Hammock 1',
  url: 'http://goo.gl/CBO3cf' }
3
Done with function...
```

Why do console.log("Length of MyArray:") and console.log(myArray.length) get called before the 7 calls of console.log in findStuff? The for-loop never does anything because myArray has length of 0 when the loop is entered. Why would the for-loop occur before findStuff gets called? Or does findStuff not actually change the value of myArray? Either way, I'm stuck. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `db.collection('images').find()` is executing asynchronously. That means it will get queued up to run next time nothing else is running. So `db.collection('images').find()` hasn't had a chance to complete before you call the rest of your code.

To run some code after the data has been retrieved, [provide a callback](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find).

```
db.collection('images').find(function(err, results) {
  ...
});
```